# How to create perpendicular edges along one direction?

Tags: bezier-curves, svg

I made path in Inkscape, import it to Blender and make it 3d.  Now I need to bend it in one direction but wires connected to non-perpendicular points. Please look at image to understant what i mean.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think there's any automatic way to do that, for example you could create a grid above your mesh and use the Knife Project tool?

Comment: Should I make mesh from bezier curve at first?

Comment: what do you mean? It's already a mesh

Comment: When I import it from svg - it's bezier curve. But then I convert it to mesh.

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots added to post

Comment: it makes my Blender crash, I'm not sure what you mean, what you show in the screenshot is a mesh, you were right to convert to mesh, now you could do what you want to do with a tool like Knife Project tool, I can make a full answer if needed

Comment: Hmm. Okay. I will try it, but maybe I making something wrong and it can be made much easy? Here is SVG image. I need to import it to blender and bend in single dimension like i described in preview. https://svgur.com/s/Fpc

Comment: @br. as moonboots said, this can be done easily enough using "Knife Project" <= That's your search keyword

Comment: How about MeshDeformModifier ... you put a cage around your mesh (a simple box will do) and deform the cage.  Make sure you have enough divisions in you cage to do what you want.  I can write this up as an answer if this is of interest.

Comment: Will try both and will say how solved, thanks

Comment: actually what's the reason why you want to keep parallel edges?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by creating a plane and subdividing it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> into parallel equally spaced edges, then using Knife Project tool, you can project your object to the plane, all you need to do later is to remove all the faces that fall outside the projected faces.
But looking at your file, you need ***first*** to turn your object into a mesh using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and choose Mesh from curve, then in edit mode, select all, press <kbd>X</kbd> and choose Limited Disolve, in order to reduce the vertices in your object.
Here's your edited file: 
[image]

Comment: Ctrl + r may not work because they will stay parreale to the mesh.

Comment: Ctrl + R is to be used on the plane, not the object @Yohello1

Comment: Okay then it should work fine.